# Extract attribute value from html element

Tags: regex

Been struggling with this for a couple of hours now...

I have the following regex:

```
(?<=\bdata-video-id=""."">)(.*?)(title=.*?>)
```

The following input:

```
         <div class="cameras">            
            <table class="results">
                <colgroup>
                    <col class="col0">
                    <col class="col1">
                </colgroup>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th title="Name">
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th title="Date">
                            Date
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr data-video-id="1">
                        <td title="149 - Cam123">
                            149 - Cam123
                        </td>
                        <td title="Feb 18 2013">
                            Feb 18 2013
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-video-id="2">
                        <td title="150 - Cam456">
                            150 - Cam456
                        </td>
                        <td title="Feb 18 2013">
                            Feb 18 2013
                        </td>
                    </tr>                   
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

The regex outputs this:

```
<td title="149 - Cam123">
<td title="150 - Cam456">
```

But what I'd like to get is the contents of the title attribute of the **1st** cell from every table row:

```
149 - Cam123
150 - Cam456
```

The number of rows may obviously vary but the number of columns is fixed. 
Please help me fine tune the above regex.
Thanks

**NOTE**: The solution **MUST** be a regular expression. I do not have access to the code base therefore an HTML parser or any other kind of code intervention is not possible. The only way I can hook into the application is by injecting a different regex.

Comment: in what language? also where is input?

Comment: Why a Regex? Use a html parser.

Comment: **[obligatory ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡  link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/664108)**

Comment: I found a rule, any regex + xml/html codes questions would be commented/answered with "why not a parser" yes, if parsing the whole xml/html document, regex won't be the right choice. however, in many cases, our program reading a **part** of text, which are some html/xml elements in certain format. in this case, regex does work. Also works for very simple xml/html structure with fixed format case. or we have to import a new library and write dozen lines codes just for getting an attribute.  well my 2 cents...

Comment: Please post the input.

Comment: input posted along with a short explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the OP requirements that it MUST be a regex, then my suggestion would be to add a group wrapper to the inner title information:

```
(?<=\bdata-video-id=""."">).*?title="(.*?)">
```

Otherwise, the general solution is to not use a regex:

Why are you using a regex? The typical solution for this due to the complexities of the tags is to use an HTML parser

[Here is a SO about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

[Here is another even more popular response on using regex for XHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) which was pointed out by [Jeff Atwood in this blogpost](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Comment: Yep, I know. However this is something running on customer premise and I cannot change the code base. It has some kind of regular expression engine which I can inject regexes into without touching the code base.

Comment: I have updated my answer in that case. Please be careful with this per the links I provided as regex is not suggested here

Comment: hmmm...that didn't do the trick. can you please post the full regex, I'm not too much of a regex guy...

Comment: @zaf As rrrr commented, could you post the input. I think I was going off of the wrong input

Comment: input posted along with a short explanation